# openstreetmap to overlay android mapview

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap

I am trying to put a small area of openstreetmap onto the mapview and override the Google maps. How can i go about doing this? How do I even get started?

I am new to this concept, so I would appreciate if someone could lead me.

Currently, I have downloaded the map.osm file of the region I want. Now I have no clue on what direction I should take.

Sorry about this ignorance.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use osmdroid:
http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/
They have extensive explanations, examples, wiki, etc.